# undefined method `order_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000102efef18>:0x00000100f3c9c8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my controller file:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

   ...

   def create
     @order = current_user.current_cart.order #get a current order
     if @order.nil?
       @order = current_user.current_cart.build_order #if one does not exist, create it
     end
     @order.update_attributes!(...) #update the attributes
     render :new
   end

   ...
end
```

I get a "`undefined method 'order_path'`" error whenever I try to save/update the order model.

This is the simplified version of the view:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

Whenever `@order = Order.new` it works, and if I do `@order = current_user.current_cart.order`, it works. But, as soon as I save something or update something before rendering a template, it gives me the error. I would like to save the model.

In the routes the order is a simple resources :orders.

Comment: The error should be a clue.  It's missing the order_path, which isn't surprising since you are defining a route for plural orders in your routes file.

Comment: So I have to add resources :order? Then what would be the best way to make sure that the resources :order goes to the :orders controller? Or is there something I can just put in the resources :orders to fix this problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, resource :order did solve the problem, but I had to do other stuff to the form_for to make it work perfectly. Thanks for the tip Marc!

Answer (score 0):

I have same error. When **routes.rb**

```
resources :orders, only: [:index, :create, :edit] do
  # ...
end
```

### Solution

add `:update`

```
resources :orders, only: [:index, :create, :edit, :update] do
  # ...
end
```